# SendMessageTimeout API in Perl

Tags: perl, perl-module, mod-perl

I am trying to replace SendMessage API with SendMessageTimeout in an installation script (that refreshes the environment -- registry and stuff). After replacing the installer is crashing. I have compiled the sub routine separately and it works alright.

Is it because SendMessageTimeout is in a different module -- Win32::GUI? I am unable to find a source to download this module. Apologies for the naivety, I am totally new to Perl and this is the only change I had to make.

```
use Win32::API;  

sub refreshEnvironment()
{
use constant WM_WININICHANGE => 0x001A;
use constant HWND_BROADCAST  => 0xffff;
use constant SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG => 0x0002;

    print("Refreshing the environment.\n");
    my $sm = new Win32::API(
            "user32",
            "SendMessageTimeout",
            ['N', 'N', 'I', 'P', 'N','I', 'P'], 'N'
        );

    if (! defined ($sm)) {
        print("SendMessage api did not initialize.\n");
        return;
    }

    my $buffer = "Environment";

    my $res = $sm->Call(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_WININICHANGE, 0, $buffer, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 2000, NULL);
    print("SendMessage refresh environment done\n");
}

refreshEnvironment();
```

Comment: `SendMessageTimeout` is a method of `Win32::GUI` module. You may use it as `Win32::GUI::SendMessageTimeout(MSG, WPARAM, LPARAM, [FLAGS], TIMEOUT);`

Comment: Thank you @ChankeyPathak. I installed win32-gui module and compiled -- it worked fine locally.